# Iteratively creating variables: What are safe alternatives to globals()?

Tags: python, global-variables, global

In S/O threads about iteratively creating variables, most replies suggest using `globals()`, but highlight the fact that it is dangerous to play with the global scope. 
Yet, `locals()` and `vars()` can also be used to iteratively create variables. For instance:

```py
for i in range(1, 6):
    vars()[f'variable_{i}'] = i

print(key for key in vars().keys() if 'variable' in key)
```

`Out[2]: ['variable_1', 'variable_2', 'variable_3', 'variable_4', 'variable_5']`

Are `locals()` and `vars()` safe to iteratively create variables? If so, why are they never mentioned, as opposed to `globals()`?

Comment: *Don't* iteratively create variables. Iteratively populate a `dict` whose keys are the names you would have used for the variables.

Comment: In the global scope, `vars()` and `locals()` are equivalent to `globals()`.

Comment: Since there is no guarantee that modifying the output of `vars` will actually affect the local scope, you are just using a `dict` in a very convoluted way.

Comment: Creating variables at run-time is strange. I would avoid it. Source code should be easy to read and obvious (not tricky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning to the output of `vars` doesn't actually modify the local scope; it just populates a mapping which you can only access via `vars()`. Observer:

```
>>> def bar():
...   for i in range(6):
...     vars()[f'var_{i}'] = i
...   print(vars()['var_3'])
...   print(var_3)
...
>>> bar()
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in bar
NameError: name 'var_3' is not defined
```

Since you are already commited to mapping semantics, you may as well just use a `dict`:

```
def bar():
    data = {}
    for i in range(6):
        data[f'var_{i}'] = i
    print(data['var_3'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Not, it is not safe to use [`vars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) or [`locals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) that way. From the documentation:

[`vars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars):

> Without an argument, [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) acts like [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals). Note, the locals dictionary is only useful for reads since updates to the locals dictionary are ignored.

[`locals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals):

> **Note**: The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

In the case of [`locals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals), one could give that note the interpretation that you should not change the *existing* contents in the returned dictionary (as opposed to introducing new contents). Still, nothing in the documentation suggests that introducing new values in the dictionary should have any effect.